# using AdMob in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, admob

I'm trying to use adMob in my iOS app and I'm unable to build the project because I'm getting the errors you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Build errors]
It seems it's being caused by a file with ".a" extension in the admob SDK.
I believe it is a library or something like that.
How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some frameworks to your project.

1. Click on the project in Xcode
2. Click on the target
3. Click on Build Phases
4. Click on Link Binary With Libraries
5. Click on the plus sign
6. Add SystemConfiguration.framework, MessageUI.framework, AudioToolbox.framework to your project